# Ember bind-attr deprecated, how to rewrite using new preferred approach?

Tags: ember.js

I'm an Ember newbie, and am trying to alter the following handlebars/template line of code to not use the deprecated bind-attr approach (NOTE: the code is used to sort a table and show an up/down icon accordingly, and is taken from here: http://jsbin.com/bebev/1/edit?html,js,output; linked to from here: http://www.jarrodctaylor.com/posts/Filter-And-Sort-Tables-In-Ember/):

```
<span {{bind-attr class="sortedOnID:sorted glyphiconDirection :glyphicon"}}></span>
```

I've found some examples online (e.g., https://github.com/machty/emblem.js/issues/242) of how to move away from the deprecated approach, but I can't seem to apply them to this.

I've tried several permutations, but can't figure out how to re-write it to keep the old functionality. E.g., none of the following are working for me:

```
<span class={{if sortedOnID "sorted glyphiconDirection :glyphicon"}}></span>

<span class={{if sortedOnID "sorted"}} {{if sortedOnID "glyphiconDirection :glyphicon"}}></span>

<span class="{{if sortedOnID "sorted glyphiconDirection :glyphicon"}}"></span>
```

Can anyone provide some guidance? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but this is the basic idea.

```
class="{{if sortedOnId 'sorted'}} {{if glyphiconDirection 'glyphicon-direction'}} glyphicon"
```

1. Plain old classes which were specified using the leading colons are just given as is.
2. Conditional classes using `var:class` are replaced with `if`.
3. Simple variables, which were turned into dasherized classnames if true, must be given using `if`.

Comment: It's worth nothing that you can also use the `unless` helper to replace the `var::class` behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, torazaburo. I'm still having trouble getting this to work. Could you possibly say a bit more about why in your example  the glyphicon" part has to go outside the second of braces? I don't understand what's happening there in terms of your list.

Comment: Within `{{bind-attr}}`, `:class` means to add the literal classname `class`. The equivalent way to do that using the new syntax is just to put `class` in the list of classes, outside curly brackets.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Was able to get this working. Appreciate the help.  For anyone curious, <span class="{{if sortedOnID 'sorted'}} {{glyphiconDirection}} glyphicon"></span> ; note that I had a typo in the original sortedOnId, and also should have mentioned originally that glyphiconDirection is calling a function.